# Geometric intuition for standard étale morphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Rings are commutative and unitary.

Say a ring morphism is standard étale if it's isomorphic to one of the form $k\to k[x]_g/ \left\langle f \right\rangle$ for $k$ some ring, $f,g\in k[x]$ such that $f^\prime$ is invertible in $k[x]_g/ \left\langle f \right\rangle$.

What's the geometric intuition for this? It looks like a condition to ensure some Jacobian will end up being nonzero, but I'm not sure which one. Also, why do these sometimes restrict to $f$ monic?

Geometrically it seems $ \operatorname{Spec} k[x]_g$ is the germ of the geometric line $ \operatorname{Spec} k[x]$ at the point $g$. What is $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]_g/\left\langle f \right\rangle $ geometrically? "Zeroing" the roots of $f$ in this germ? Does being standard étale mean $f^\prime $ does not have any roots of $f$ in this germ at $g$?

How to work this out algebraically as well?

Comment: $\mathrm{Spec }k[x]_g$ is the open set where the function $g$ does not vanish. $\mathrm{Spec }k[x]_g/(f)$ is the vanishing set of $f$ relative to this open set (i.e. intersection). $f'$ being invertible in $k[x]_g/(f)$ means that $f'$ is non-vanishing on this set.

Comment: @PavelČoupek so all this just means that we can find $f,g$ such that $f$ has simple roots on $ \operatorname{Spec} k[x]_g$?

Comment: Yes, I would say so. In some tame enough example, one can imagine $\mathrm{Spec}k[x]$ as taking a product of your original space $\mathrm{Spec}k$ with a line. Then the map is basically a projection from the relative vanishing set of $f$ to your original space. I imagine the condition on $f'$ should ensure something like this projection map being locally invertible (but this is just a guess based on the implicit function theorem intuition)